# Usefullness of Graphical Models in practice

Tags: regression, mixed-model, assumptions, graphical-model

Graphical Models uses that correlation 0 is equivalent to independence for multivariate normal distribution. Then we can make a graph where there is an edge between two nodes if the correlation is not 0. Then we can establish conditional independence of componenets in our graph. But unlike regression methods which is somewhat robust to violations of the assumptions, this property is just false when you don't have truly multivariate normal distribution, so how is this ever useful in practice?

In my class we used the above property in various places, like fitting a MGLLM (multivariate generalized linear mixed model) and then concluding that some variables are conditionally independent of the variables of interest given some random components.

But yeah, I just don't see how this is actually valid to do on any data, since it won't ever be actually multivariate normally distributed.

My question is which of the following is true:

1. Distributions which are closer to multivariate normal almost has the property that correlation 0 equivalent to independence.

I just don’t see why a multivariate Gamma (with high k) more so has that property compared to something far away, say multivariate uniform$[0,1]$ or multivariate poisson($1$).

2. We in general just assume correlation 0 equivalent to independence.

But then we don’t care about how close our data is to multivariate normal, which we seem to do in litterature.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! These normality properties are false in standard regressions, too, just often only slightly false (but still false). That's what it means to be robust (more or less). How do you know this method to lack robustness?

Comment: I'm aware about regression, even wrote it myself in the post? 

But either variables are (conditionally) independent, or they aren't. So how does your data being close to normal distribution help in anyway? This is much different than regression from my pov.

Comment: Robust to whatever violations there are..how do you figure there is robustness in regular regression but not in what you're doing?

Comment: Because something which is close to a multivariate normal distribution could have correlation 0 but be very dependent.

Comment: And regular regression can have its robustness broken by a sufficiently severe deviation from the ideal. What leads you to believe that what you're doing behaves any differently?

Comment: Because I don't see how this property becomes better when its somewhat close to multivariate normal. To me we are essentially just saying correlation 0 equivalent to independence no matter what. How does it being close to multivariate normal distribution impact it all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated the post to hopefully make my question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Model assumptions are formal constructs, and as such they never hold in reality ("all models are wrong but some are useful"). Model assumptions are used to set up methods and procedures that are guaranteed to work in an idealised formal situation. We can't really do better than that as reality is too complex for any model.

The question whether reality is different from the model *in ways that can with good probability cause results of the model-based procedure to be misleading* is always a good and relevant one. In fact there are also well known issues with standard linear regression, because a distribution that produces with very small probability outliers that are detrimental to the regression can in fact be seen as very similar to the assumed model with i.i.d. normal residuals and linear relation.

Regarding the normality assumption in graphical models, note that also *stochastic independence* is a formal and idealised assumption that will not perfectly hold in reality as arguably everything in some way depends on everything else. You are basically saying that we are really interested in independence whereas we are using correlation based on the normality assumption, and for non-normal data correlation isn't the same as independence, different from the situation under normality.

I'd however say that it makes as little sense to demand precise independence as it makes sense to demand precise normality. The reasoning of normal distribution-based graphical models is appropriate in situations in which correlation is a good measure for the kind of dependence that is relevant in a particular application. This may happen if any nonlinearity is very mild and relations are still monotonic, or if for some reason only dependence is relevant in a given application that is monotonic, i.e., associated with nonzero correlation (arguably sometimes a relationship is monotonic but so nonlinear that correlation isn't appropriate, but then sometimes in such situations transformation can help). This is not always the case, so there can be problems, and there should be appropriate diagnosis of potential issues with the model assumptions, but for sure applications of this kind do not require perfect normality, and therefore graphical models can be applied with success in a range of practical situations that are not perfectly normal.

There is some work on non-normal graphical models by the way. Much of this uses normality-based theory as a starting point, so there is relevance in knowing about the normal case before going on to more general setups.